# Problems with LocationListener in api 22

Tags: java, android, class, debugging

I don't know why in api 22 my program doesn't work but works very well in api 29.
I want to be operational in api 22.

Why is my listener is defined by the class MainController ?

Why is my Localisation is always null ?

Why  is `public void onLocationChanged(Location location)` is never called ?

[localisationListener isn't a class of LocalisationListener but of my controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0hKi.png)

[watch the import](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VTxzW.png)

Also :

In api 22 `this.location` is equal to null (that i doesn't want)

In api 29 `this.location` is not equal to null (that i want)

```java
        locationManager = (LocationManager) activity.getSystemService(MainActivity.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, minTime, minDistance, locationListener);
            this.location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        }
        else if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER)) {
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER, minTime, minDistance, locationListener);
            this.location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER);
        }
        else if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) {
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, minTime, minDistance, locationListener);
            this.location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        }
```

But in my research in found an error in debugging

- In api 22, `onLocationChanged` is never call (that i doesn't want)
- In api 29, `onLocationChanged` is call (that i want)
- In api 22 and 29, localisationListener isn't defined by the interface `LocalisationListener` but by the class `MainController`

```java
locationListener = new LocationListener() {
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Log.i(MainActivity.LOG_I, "During Try:" + location.toString());

        MainController.this.location = location;

        if(googleMap != null && updateLocalisationGoogleMaps != null) updateLocalisationGoogleMaps.update(googleMap, location);

        if (updateLocalisation != null) updateLocalisation.update(location);

    }
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
}
```

Comment: Hi, I am reviewing your post. Although a good question, it is always a good idea to add some code, so that the community knows what your already have worked on and can help you better.

Comment: I post my code in the image sended
+ localisationListener isn't a class of LocalisationListener but of my controller
+ watch the import
when you click it in you cannot watch it ?

Comment: Should should put the code into the query